# Express Error Handling Opinion & Best Practice

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I have more of a code architecture question about error handling NodeJs Express apps. I am not sure on what is the best pattern for error handling. On that note, what situations should be considered as an error. For instance, is a 401 Unauthorized code considered an error even though this response is expected when sending bad credentials?

When using:

```
//app.js file
app.use(err, req, res, next){}
```

I generally tend to only put 5xx errors here which would represent situations in which a database cannot be found or no network connection issue or function failures. As for the rest, I would manually send back a status code, such as a 401, from the controller by explicitly coding `res.status(xxx).send();` or something of the sort. But the issue behind what I'm doing is I tend to repeat myself and have to place logging scattered across the app. Is my approach fine? Should I instead be creating multiple error handling middlewares for different ranges of status codes? I need an opnion

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) with your custom error class to deal with this problem.

Let's see a error class, which contains a custom error message, http status code and logLevel if incase you employ logger.

```
module.exports = class ApiCalError extends Error {
  constructor (message, status, logLevel) {

    // Calling parent constructor of base Error class.
    super(message);

    // Capturing stack trace, excluding constructor call from it.
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);

    // Saving class name in the property of our custom error as a shortcut.
    this.name = this.constructor.name;

    // You can use any additional properties you want.
    // I'm going to use preferred HTTP status for this error types.
    // `500` is the default value if not specified.
    this.status = status || 400;

    this.logLevel = logLevel || 'warn';

  }

  toResponseJSON () {
    return {
        success: false,
        message: this.message
    }
  }
};
```

Now, let's took a look at a controller. We have only sent successful response from this controller, and passed custom errors to middleware.

```
  exports.Login = function(req, res, next) {
        const validationResult = validateLoginForm(req.body)
        if (!validationResult.success) {
            var err = new customError(validationResult.message, 400, 'warn')
            return next(err)
        } else {
            return passport.authenticate('local-login', (err, token, userData) => {
                if (err) {
                    if (err.name == 'IncorrectCredentialsError' || err.name == 'EmailNotVerified') {
                        var error = new customError(err.message, 400, 'warn')
                        return next(error)
                    }
                    return next(err)
                }
                return res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'You have successfully logged in!',
                    token,
                    user: userData
                })
            })(req, res, next)
        }
    }
```

Now, let's take a look at logger and error handlers middlewares. Here, logger will log the errors in api and pass the error to error handlers. These functions would then be used in `app.use()`.

```
    // Import library

    var Logger = function(logger) {
        return function(err, req, res, next) {
            var meta = {
                path: req.originalUrl,
                method: req.method,
                'user-agent': req.headers['user-agent'],
                origin: req.headers.origin 
            }
            if (err instanceof customError) {
                logger.log(err.logLevel, err.message, meta)
                return next(err)
            } else {
                logger.log('error', err.message, meta)
                return next(err)
            }
        }   
    }
    var ErrorHandler = function() {
        return function(err, req, res, next) {
            if (err instanceof customError) {
                return res.status(err.status).json(err.toResponseJSON())
            }else{
                return res.status(500).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: err.message
                })
            }
        }
    }

    module.exports = {
        Logger,
        ErrorHandler
    }
```